# How To Combine Multiple std::function To One?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std-function, stdbind

I have multiple `std::function`. Each of them have different input and output, and the input of one `std::function` might be the output of another `std::function`, which means that "serial" convert from one to another.

Maybe I can't describe it clear enough. Let code talks

```
std::function<bool(double)> combine(std::function<int(double)> convert1
                                    , std::function<char(int)> convert2
                                    , std::function<bool(char)> convert3)
{
    return std::bind(convert1, convert2, convert3)//error. A function directly convert [double] to [bool] using convert1, convert2, convert3
}
```

Here is very simple code which I already remove the pointless code and show the core of my meaning.

So you can see `convert1` do conversion from `double` to `int`, `convert2` do conversion from `int` to `char` and `convert3` do conversion from `char` to `bool`. Now I need to combine them together and so that I can directly convert `double` to `bool`.

And you know, I am not really want to convert `double` to `bool`. It's only for test.

One option to implement this is that write a help function:

```
bool helper(double d
            , std::function<int(double)> convert1
            , std::function<char(int)> convert2
            , std::function<bool(char)> convert3)
{
    return convert3(convert2(convert1(d)));
}

std::function<double(bool)> combine(std::function<int(double)> convert1
                                    , std::function<char(int)> convert2
                                    , std::function<bool(char)> convert3)
{
    return helper;
}
```

But it's ugly code and maybe I use this conversion in a common way, which means that I should write this `helper` for all kind of my conversion.

So, is there a directly way to combine these function together?

Comment: have you tried lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a simple type traits to extract the input type of the last function

```
template <typename, typename...>
struct lastFnType;

template <typename F0, typename F1, typename ... Fn>
struct lastFnType<F0, F1, Fn...>
 { using type = typename lastFnType<F1, Fn...>::type; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct lastFnType<std::function<T2(T1)>>
 { using type = T1; };
```

you can transform the apple apple's solution (+1) in a more general variadic template recursive solution

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::function<T1(T2)> combine (std::function<T1(T2)> conv)
 { return conv; }

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename ... Fn>
std::function<T1(typename lastFnType<std::function<T2(T3)>, Fn...>::type)>
    combine (std::function<T1(T2)> conv1, std::function<T2(T3)> conv2, 
             Fn ... fn)
 {
   using In = typename lastFnType<std::function<T2(T3)>, Fn...>::type;

   return [=](In const & in){ return conv1(combine(conv2, fn...)(in)); };
 }
```

But observe that the order of the converter is inverted (call with last used converter first; so `combine(convert3, convert2, convert1)`)

The following is a full example

```
#include <functional>

template <typename, typename...>
struct lastFnType;

template <typename F0, typename F1, typename ... Fn>
struct lastFnType<F0, F1, Fn...>
 { using type = typename lastFnType<F1, Fn...>::type; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct lastFnType<std::function<T2(T1)>>
 { using type = T1; };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::function<T1(T2)> combine (std::function<T1(T2)> conv)
 { return conv; }

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename ... Fn>
std::function<T1(typename lastFnType<std::function<T2(T3)>, Fn...>::type)>
    combine (std::function<T1(T2)> conv1, std::function<T2(T3)> conv2, 
             Fn ... fn)
 {
   using In = typename lastFnType<std::function<T2(T3)>, Fn...>::type;

   return [=](In const & in){ return conv1(combine(conv2, fn...)(in)); };
 }

int fn1 (double d)
 { return d*2.0; }

char fn2 (int i)
 { return i+3; }

bool fn3 (char c)
 { return c == 'a'; }


int main ()
 {
   std::function<int(double)> f1 { fn1 };
   std::function<char(int)> f2 { fn2 };
   std::function<bool(char)> f3 { fn3 };

   auto cmb = combine(f3, f2, f1);

   bool b { cmb(3.2) };
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use lambda expression to do this.

---

```
std::function<bool(double)> combine(std::function<int(double)> convert1
                                    , std::function<char(int)> convert2
                                    , std::function<bool(char)> convert3)
{
    return [=](double d){return convert3(convert2(convert1(d)));}
}
```

---

Or you can use lambda directly in your code and do not use this `combine` function at all, also it would be more clear what happened.

---

If you still want use combine function and want a more generic one, maybe you can try something like this. (just a simple example)

```
template<typename Converter>
auto combineX(Converter converter){
   return converter;
}

template<typename Converter, typename ...Converters>
auto combineX(Converter converter, Converters... converters){
   return [converter,remain = combineX(converters...)](auto x){return remain(converter(x));};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
decltype(auto) apply(T&& t, F&& f)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template <typename T, typename F, typename... Fs>
decltype(auto) apply(T&& t, F&& f, Fs&&... fs)
{
    return apply(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(t)), std::forward<Fs>(fs)...);
}
```

with usage:

```
apply(4,
      [](int i) { return i * 10; },
      [](auto i) {return i + 2;},
      [](auto n){ return n / 10.f; })
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b12f5bba84a6a5d)